# Multisite configuration with multiple domains and subdomains

Tags: 7, multi-sites

Im using CPanel and Drupal 7.

In CPanel I have created 2 domains and pointed to my drupal installation.
In the drupal sites folder I have added a folder for each domain and added the settings file.

When I navigate to either of the 2 domains I see the two Drupal installs.

I am now trying to add subdomains of each of the sites. I create the subdomains in CPanel, point them to the Drupal install. Added the subdomain folders with the settings files. But when I navigate to the subdomains I get a page not found error.

For clarity the below will help to illustrate my set up.

```
example.com uses sites/default
example1.com uses sites/example1.com
example2.com uses sites/example2.com
```

The above is working, but these 2 subdomains do not resolve:

```
subdomain.example1.com should use sites/subdomain.example1.com
and subdomain.example2.com should use sites/subdomain.example2.com
```

How do I correctly set up these subdomains?

Comment: Does "do not resolve" mean the browser cannot lookup the site (eg no DNS entry), or that the browser does connect to something but not the right something? Perhaps you could clarify the error messages, etc...  Also, could you say exactly what "create the subdomains in CPanel" means, for those who don't use CPanel regularly?

Comment: CPanel creates its own folders for the subdomains. How were you able to point them to the Drupal folder instead? Usually you need to create a symlink from the subdomain folder to the Drupal folder.

Comment: Hi @rivimey, when I visit the URL it says this page can't be found. I think it might be a name server problem but not sure. prkos, in cpanel I go to add subdomain, there is a drop down menu where I select the top domain, then enter the subdomain for that domain, the top domain is loading correctly. When cpanel asks which folder I set as the drupal folder instead of the default subdomain folder.